# How to copy style type in Word

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2016

As you can see in the picture, I would like just to copy style type(box). So it will add new box; e.g. when copy "Normal" box you end up with something like "Copy of Normal". Similar when you copy file/folder in Windows Explorer. And then you would edit that style box separately as new style box.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to write a paragraph of text, select it, apply style, select it (sometime it loose selection) and from styles click on bottom right icon, then A+ and create new style.